# Unit testing unknown fields in grpc

Tags: c#, unit-testing, grpc, proto

I am trying to write unit tests for code generated by grpc(autogen code). how can we write tests for unknown fields generated in autogen.

below is the code for the request message.

```
public HelloRequest(HelloRequest other) : this()
{
    name_ = other.name_;
    _unknownFields = pb::UnknownFieldSet.Clone(other._unknownFields);
}
```

I wrote a normal unit test which covers fields in request, but i am not sure how to cover unknown fields for code coverage purpose.

Comment: The example snippet you posted has little to do with gRPC outside of the fact that you generated the code with the Grpc.Tools codegen.  Basically, generated code for any protobuf message will contain the "unknownFields" container for storing unknown fields. Also, I don't think you need to come up with unit test coverage for protobuf-generated code - most projects should focus on increasing code coverage for their their own code (and skip code coverage for generated code). The protobuf C# has lots of its own tests and there doesn't seem to be any need for you to duplicate their code/tests.

Comment: See https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/tree/main/csharp/src/Google.Protobuf.Test for protobuf C#'s tests.

Comment: Thanks @JanTattermusch, is there a attribute which I can have it as part of code which might exclude the autogen code from coverage. i know to manually exclude in code coverage tool, apart from that if there is a way.